# Filtering dataset using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to apply an algorithm to the FMA dataset. This dataset is available in https://github.com/mdeff/fma, and I downloaded the  fma_metadata.zip.

The FMA dataset consists of 106,574 music tracks represented by 518 features, corresponding to 7
statistics (mean, standard deviation, skew, kurtosis, median, minimum, maximum) calculated from
74 time-based acoustic characteristics. See the dataset description for more details.
The first three lines in the features.csv file identify the feature in each column: the first line indicates the feature group, the second line the statistics, and the third line the feature number within each feature group. Some examples of feature identifiers are then ‘tonnetz skew 06’, ‘chroma cqt kurtosis 09’, ‘mfcc max 08’, ‘spectral contrast median 07’.

My goal is to apply a clustering algorithm using PySpark (and only RDDs, not DataFrames) to the small subset (8000 songs). I should be able to select the small dataset, filtering by the field subset in the tracks.csv file.

The tracks.csv file has this form:

```py
,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,album,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,artist,set,set,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track,track
,comments,date_created,date_released,engineer,favorites,id,information,listens,producer,tags,title,tracks,type,active_year_begin,active_year_end,associated_labels,bio,comments,date_created,favorites,id,latitude,location,longitude,members,name,related_projects,tags,website,wikipedia_page,split,subset,bit_rate,comments,composer,date_created,date_recorded,duration,favorites,genre_top,genres,genres_all,information,interest,language_code,license,listens,lyricist,number,publisher,tags,title
track_id,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2,0,2008-11-26 01:44:45,2009-01-05 00:00:00,,4,1,<p></p>,6073,,[],AWOL - A Way Of Life,7,Album,2006-01-01 00:00:00,,,"<p>A Way Of Life, A Collective of Hip-Hop from NJ...................</p>",0,2008-11-26 01:42:32,9,1,40.0583238,New Jersey,-74.4056612,"Sajje Morocco,Brownbum,ZawidaGod,Custodian of Records,Zooberelli the Don,F.A.H,MadSicka,Damien Omenicci..and a van load more...",AWOL,The list of past projects is 2 long but every1 and every style from Tabby Bonet 2 M.O.P..Azillion Records Flagship trackmaster DJ BrownBum is a beat Wizard.....A-2-Z..illion....(right now working with JerseyBlock Ent),['awol'],http://www.AzillionRecords.blogspot.com,,training,small,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:48:12,2008-11-26 00:00:00,168,2,Hip-Hop,[21],[21],,4656,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 International,1293,,3,,[],Food
3,0,2008-11-26 01:44:45,2009-01-05 00:00:00,,4,1,<p></p>,6073,,[],AWOL - A Way Of Life,7,Album,2006-01-01 00:00:00,,,"<p>A Way Of Life, A Collective of Hip-Hop from NJ...................</p>",0,2008-11-26 01:42:32,9,1,40.0583238,New Jersey,-74.4056612,"Sajje Morocco,Brownbum,ZawidaGod,Custodian of Records,Zooberelli the Don,F.A.H,MadSicka,Damien Omenicci..and a van load more...",AWOL,The list of past projects is 2 long but every1 and every style from Tabby Bonet 2 M.O.P..Azillion Records Flagship trackmaster DJ BrownBum is a beat Wizard.....A-2-Z..illion....(right now working with JerseyBlock Ent),['awol'],http://www.AzillionRecords.blogspot.com,,training,medium,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:48:14,2008-11-26 00:00:00,237,1,Hip-Hop,[21],[21],,1470,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 International,514,,4,,[],Electric Ave
5,0,2008-11-26 01:44:45,2009-01-05 00:00:00,,4,1,<p></p>,6073,,[],AWOL - A Way Of Life,7,Album,2006-01-01 00:00:00,,,"<p>A Way Of Life, A Collective of Hip-Hop from NJ...................</p>",0,2008-11-26 01:42:32,9,1,40.0583238,New Jersey,-74.4056612,"Sajje Morocco,Brownbum,ZawidaGod,Custodian of Records,Zooberelli the Don,F.A.H,MadSicka,Damien Omenicci..and a van load more...",AWOL,The list of past projects is 2 long but every1 and every style from Tabby Bonet 2 M.O.P..Azillion Records Flagship trackmaster DJ BrownBum is a beat Wizard.....A-2-Z..illion....(right now working with JerseyBlock Ent),['awol'],http://www.AzillionRecords.blogspot.com,,training,small,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:48:20,2008-11-26 00:00:00,206,6,Hip-Hop,[21],[21],,1933,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 International,1151,,6,,[],This World
10,0,2008-11-26 01:45:08,2008-02-06 00:00:00,,4,6,,47632,,[],Constant Hitmaker,2,Album,,,"Mexican Summer, Richie Records, Woodsist, Skulltones","<p><span style=""font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial;font-size:xx-small;"">""Philly's Constant Hitmaker"" Kurt Vile plays psychedelic experimental pop infused with a classic, folksy directness. 2008's Gulcher Records release <i>Constant Hitmaker</i> more than lives up to the name. Vile's a consistent live performer who's shared the stage with a range of sonic adventurers and avant pop-stars including Sonic Youth, Big Star, Blues Control, Magik Markers, and Ariel Pink's Haunted Graffiti.</span></p><p><span style=""font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial;font-size:xx-small;"">After a slew of limited releases on labels like Mexican Summer, Richie Records, Woodsist, and Skulltones,</span><span style=""font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial;font-size:xx-small;""> Kurt Vile signed to Matador Records who released his first proper full-length (the Gulcher release was more of a ""greatest hits""), <a title=""Childish Prodigy"" href=""http://www.matadorrecords.com/store/index.php?catalog_id=387"">Childish Prodigy</a>.<br /></span></p>",3,2008-11-26 01:42:55,74,6,,,,"Kurt Vile, the Violators",Kurt Vile,,"['philly', 'kurt vile']",http://kurtvile.com,,training,small,192000,0,Kurt Vile,2008-11-25 17:49:06,2008-11-26 00:00:00,161,178,Pop,[10],[10],,54881,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives (aka Music Sharing) 3.0 International,50135,,1,,[],Freeway
20,0,2008-11-26 01:45:05,2009-01-06 00:00:00,,2,4,"<p> ""spiritual songs"" from Nicky Cook</p>",2710,,[],Niris,13,Album,1990-01-01 00:00:00,2011-01-01 00:00:00,,"<p>Songs written by: Nicky Cook</p>
<p>VOCALS, CAJON AND TABLA+ UKELELE</p>",2,2008-11-26 01:42:52,10,4,51.895927,Colchester England,0.891874,"Nicky Cook
",Nicky Cook,,"['instrumentals', 'experimental pop', 'post punk', 'experimental rock', 'soundtracks', 'lo fi', 'nicky', 'impro', 'cook', 'nicky andrews', 'ukelele', 'nicky cook', 'singer songwriter', 'tabla']",,,training,large,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:48:56,2008-01-01 00:00:00,311,0,,"[76, 103]","[17, 10, 76, 103]",,978,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives (aka Music Sharing) 3.0 International,361,,3,,[],Spiritual Level
26,0,2008-11-26 01:45:05,2009-01-06 00:00:00,,2,4,"<p> ""spiritual songs"" from Nicky Cook</p>",2710,,[],Niris,13,Album,1990-01-01 00:00:00,2011-01-01 00:00:00,,"<p>Songs written by: Nicky Cook</p>
<p>VOCALS, CAJON AND TABLA+ UKELELE</p>",2,2008-11-26 01:42:52,10,4,51.895927,Colchester England,0.891874,"Nicky Cook
",Nicky Cook,,"['instrumentals', 'experimental pop', 'post punk', 'experimental rock', 'soundtracks', 'lo fi', 'nicky', 'impro', 'cook', 'nicky andrews', 'ukelele', 'nicky cook', 'singer songwriter', 'tabla']",,,training,large,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:49:05,2008-01-01 00:00:00,181,0,,"[76, 103]","[17, 10, 76, 103]",,1060,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives (aka Music Sharing) 3.0 International,193,,4,,[],Where is your Love?
30,0,2008-11-26 01:45:05,2009-01-06 00:00:00,,2,4,"<p> ""spiritual songs"" from Nicky Cook</p>",2710,,[],Niris,13,Album,1990-01-01 00:00:00,2011-01-01 00:00:00,,"<p>Songs written by: Nicky Cook</p>
<p>VOCALS, CAJON AND TABLA+ UKELELE</p>",2,2008-11-26 01:42:52,10,4,51.895927,Colchester England,0.891874,"Nicky Cook
",Nicky Cook,,"['instrumentals', 'experimental pop', 'post punk', 'experimental rock', 'soundtracks', 'lo fi', 'nicky', 'impro', 'cook', 'nicky andrews', 'ukelele', 'nicky cook', 'singer songwriter', 'tabla']",,,training,large,256000,0,,2008-11-26 01:49:11,2008-01-01 00:00:00,174,0,,"[76, 103]","[17, 10, 76, 103]",,718,en,Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives (aka Music Sharing) 3.0 International,612,,5,,[],Too Happy
46,0,2008-11-26 01:45:05,2009-01-06 00:00:00,,2,4,"<p> ""spiritual songs"" from Nicky Cook</p>",2710,,[],Niris,13,Album,1990-01-01 00:00:00,2011-01-01 00:00:00,,"<p>Songs written by: Nicky Cook</p>
<p>VOCALS, CAJON AND TABLA+ UKELELE</p>",2,2008-11-26 01:42:52,10,4,51.895927,Colchester England,0.891874,"Nicky Cook ...
```

I've tried many approaches but I'm not being able to implement this directly using PySpark.´
I tried doing:

```py
tracks_rdd_raw = sc.textFile("fma_metadata/tracks.csv")
def filter_subset(row):
    fields = row.split(",")
    # Check that the fields list has enough elements
    if len(fields) > 51:
        return fields[51] == "small"
    else:
        return False
small_tracks_rdd = tracks_rdd_raw.filter(filter_subset)
```

but this is not giving the right RDD.

I tried separating the header (being the first 3 rows) from the tracks_rdd and searching for the "subset" index on the second row of the header (because that's where it is). It gives me an index of 32, however when I filter the tracks_rdd by that index being == "small" I get an error saying that the index is out of range.

I have no idea how can I do this without using pandas. With pandas was pretty straightforward, I did this:

```py
data=pd.read_csv('fma_metadata/tracks.csv')
small_tracks=set(data.loc[data['set.1']=='small'][data.columns[0]].astype('float'))
data_rdd=features_rdd.filter(lambda x: x[0] in small_tracks)
```